# Aurelia UI Framework Tab Panels and Ui-Menu-Items doesnt work properly in mobile view

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-ui-framework

I'm using aurelia ui framework. When using Tab Panels and Menubar, it does not work as expected in phone view. Especially when there are many tabs so that a : (more) icon is needed to see the remaining tab-panels or menubars.
It works as expected in normal web view but it silently fails in mobile view

I tried both tab-panels and menu-bars and they both have the same issue in mobile view.

```
<ui-tab-panel active-tab.bind="activeTab">
  <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>
  <ui-tab closeable view="any.html">View</ui-tab>
  <ui-tab disabled="true">Disabled</ui-tab>

//try adding multiple tabs for mobile view so that we see that : more icon
 <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>
 <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>
 <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>
 <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>
 <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>
 <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>
 <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>
 <ui-tab view-model="anyViewModel">View Model</ui-tab>


  <compose view.bind="activeTab.view" view-model.bind="activeTab.viewModel"></compose>
</ui-tab-panel>
```

It needs to work as expected. Press :(more icon) and pressing the menu bar should trigger an action.

Comment: I think it's best to open those kind of question in the github repo. (it's more likely a bug)

Comment: oh okay. I'll do that. Thanks